# Norm and eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix, $\|\cdot\|$ be any natural norm, and $K_{p}(A)=$ $\|A\|{p}\left\|A^{-1}\right\|{p} .$ Let $\lambda_{1}$ be the smallest and $\lambda_{n}$ be the largest eigenvalues of the matrix $A^{t} A$

(b) Show that $K_{2}(A)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_{n}}{\lambda_{1}}}$. (Hint: One should use the $\|A\|=\sqrt{\rho\left(A^{t} A\right)}=\sqrt{\rho\left(A A^{t}\right)}$ relation)

For part $(b)$, it seems minimal eigenvalue of matrix $A$ will be the largest eigenvalue of the inverse of matrix $A$, so we have to use this idea but could not understand formally why square roots are needed for $K_{2}(A)$ and how spectral radius is necessary for this part?!

Comment: Provided relation would be really helpful in regards to the spectral matrix, but the square root's application is somehow vague whenever we deal with matrix norms. Are there any further suggestions for the aforementioned approach?

Comment: This question [is answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094276/81360)